# How can I get my computer to display special characters?

Tags: windows-xp, unicode, special-characters

I see tweets, for instance, with special characters in them, that will not display correctly on this system. Here is an example. For numerous of these characters, I see boxes with four characters in them.

彡☆♥彡ＧƠ Ɗ † βԼƐ໓໓ † ᗩறﻉᖇᓮCᗩ彡♥☆彡

I am using Windows XP on this system. I've seen other Windows XP systems that do display them. I don't see my answer coming up in Web searches, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Install more fonts. Put the [codepoint](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) into Google and find fonts that provide them.

Comment: Thanks and I eventually found this helping too (one or both of them, both are recommended):
http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fonts_windows.html#symbola
http://www.quivira-font.com/
The 彡 I discovered from a search is an symbol for hair in oriental family of languages.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A1